# How can two domains link to different sites of one website?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a website and two domains. Domain one should as usually link to the webpage. The second domain should link to a subpage of the website:

```
 www.domain1.com --> index.html (and all other pages)
 www.domain2.com --> otherPage.html
```

I found out that I should enable mod_rewrite and could add some rewrite rules in the .htaccess-file. How can I do this?

Any suggestions are really much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Lin's post helped me to find the working answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.ch$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ /otherPage.html [PT]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /otherPage.html [L]
```

Comment: hi Jon Lin. Thanks for your post. Unfortunately, I get an error 500 if I call www.domain2.com. I adapted the domain and filename. Unfortunately, I don't know why as I also don't really understand what those three lines do. Do you have an idea what my mistake is? What does the second/third line exactly do? Thank you!

Comment: @casaout sorry, left out a `$`